# Foggy lake - why is the fog not reflected by the water?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, reflection

I'm trying to render a foggy lake scene (Blender 2.8 with Cycles). The entire scene is placed inside a cube with a volume scatter material, the lake is just a glossy plane. The lighting comes from a large area light in the back pointing directly at the camera. Here is the setup (the ellipse is the area light):

[image: scene setup]

Here is the rendered result:

[image: render result]

As you can see, the lake reflects the light directly (bright region in the center), without any scattering applied... how can I get the water to actually reflect the fog?

Comment: Do you want blur effect? I think this will not happen: https://www.wallpaperflare.com/nature-landscape-trees-mist-blurred-sun-water-lake-reflection-wallpaper-ctbav

Comment: Try giving the lake a little bit of a rougher shading. That should improve the final render.

Comment: It looks to me like a limitation on how reflections work in cycles. Try using LuxRender  or yafaray

Comment: I'll rephrase that. Cycles is not a bidirectional path tracer and has issues with indirect light from reflective sources, hence the suggestion to try other render engines.